# boost c++ qtcreator missing function signals2.connect

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, signals, qt-creator

I am actually trying to use boost for threading in a Qt program.
I want my main thread to send an image to the main application about to change the QGraphicsSceneView.
I wrote the thread, created a signal, but The .connect function seems to be missing.

I have included boost/signals2.hpp
I also tried to include boost/signals2/connection.hpp or boost/bind.hpp but nothing works better. The autocompletion don't want to let me use .connect.

but when I want to use this function:

```
updateSignal.connect([](QImage img){updateCameraView(img);});
```

I get the following error at compilation:

> ...\cameraworker.cpp:21: erreur : no matching function for call to
>   'boost::signals2::signal::connect(CameraWorker::start()::)'
>        updateSignal.connect([](QImage img){updateCameraView(img);});

```
                                                            ^
```

I use QTCreator (not by choice), with MinGW 64, opencv and boost
I am totally new with boost.
I also want to apologize for the English mistakes I can make, English is not my mother language.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've corrected my bug:
I had to precise the use of c++11 to make boost work.
For those who will have the same error, add the line:
CONFIG += c++11
to the .pro file of your project.

If the auto-completion don't propose the .connect function, just ignore it, it works indeed.